# Call controller function from ajax returns “__RequestVerificationToken” is not present(orchard) mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, orchardcms

I am new at the Orchard,but I understand that it is like mvc.

I have some forms and buttons, I don't wont to use

```
@*@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage1","FileUpload", FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="submit" value="Save to DataBase" id="btn_UploadImg" onclick="btn_Upload_Click()" />
}
```

To catch my event on server,I want to use `onclick` and then use ajax to call my controller function.

Here is my Html **UPDATED**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script......</script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- form goes here -->

        <div class="container">
            <section id="content">

                    <form action="">
                   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <h1>Files Upload Form</h1>

   <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btn_UploadImg" onclick="btn_Upload_Click()" />
                    </form>

            </section><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- container -->

    </body>
```

My JavaScript **Updated**:

```
    function btn_Upload_Click() {

       var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UploadImage2", "FileUpload")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        sNum: "123",
        "__RequestVerificationToken": token
    },
    traditional: true,
    success: function () {
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);

    }
});

    }
```

And my controller

```
namespace VnModule.Module.Controllers
{
    public class FileUploadController : Controller
    {

     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void UploadImage1(string sNum)
    {
        int myNumber = Int32.Parse(sNum);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void UploadImage2(string sNum)
    {
        int myNumber = Int32.Parse(sNum);


    }


    }
}
```

I am getting this error: `"__RequestVerificationToken" is not present`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: put `@Html.AntiForgeryToken() `in your form

Comment: i have put it in the cshtml file on the top of all html.Or it have to be inside the form it self?

Comment: after putting @html.antiforgerytoken, add it to your ajax data,because you dont post page, you use ajax

Comment: it has to be inside the form.. `@using(){ @Html.AntiForgeryToken() // more code follows}`

Comment: If you ajax still complains you can get the value as `var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();` and pass it when you make the call

Comment: Now this error is gone,but i still cant catch event on server,i think i missing some think else,maybe my URL to function  is wrong...

Comment: check if token is created correctly via console.log(token="token"); is it there

Comment: @VovaPotapov you say the error is gone but then you say you can't catch the "event"...this doesn't add up as you should then get an exception that the action or controller cannot be found. Please update your example code above with the request verification token stuff, perhaps there is still something wrong.

Comment: I updated the code. I checked the toked,it is created correctly,the ajax error is returns empty text.

Comment: i sorry i forgot to update this part,i cant see any errors from ajax only Orchard error ":Oops something got wrong".This is not helping me to much...

Comment: Any way the question was about __RequestVerificationToken,and Lzzy resolve it,i will ask another question, because this problem is not noting to do with __RequestVerificationToken.Thanx to all  for your hepl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved by lzzy .I have Updated the code.

To resolve this you need to do this:

1.Add   `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside of your form were is your button is located.

```
   <form action="">
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btn_UploadImg" onclick="btn_Upload_Click()" />
            </form>
```

2.In your ajax add to data parameter `__RequestVerificationToken` with value of

```
$('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
```

like this

```
 data:{
   sNum: "123",
  __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
     }
```

**lzzy feel free to post your answer here,i will accept it,and remove my.**